# How to wait until queue of an ExecutorService is empty before submitting new tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using an

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

to pass *Runnable* threads for multi-threaded Java and need a barrier where the program waits until all threads that have been submitted to the ThreadPool's queue so far have *finished execution*.
Afterwards I want to continue filling the queue again. This procedure is iterated in a for-loop.

Is there an efficient method, which does not require to always shutdown the ExecutorService and instantiate a new one?

Comment: What is wrong with shutting down the service and creating a new one? Have you proven that it's too inefficient for your needs or are you just assuming it's a bad approach without testing it?

Comment: you can check `getActiveCount()` method on ThreadPoolExecutor. It's not available in ExecutorService.

Comment: You don't need to that, fixed thread pool ExecutorService has queue of tasks from which it uses for picking up

Comment: Why do you want that exactly?

Comment: @Duncan Yes, I am assuming that shutting one down and creating a new ExecutorService is inefficient. Am I wrong?

Comment: @madison54 I don't know, it depends on so many things. But it appears to be a simple solution and one shouldn't prematurely optimise simple solutions unless they prove to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @fge At the end of every iteration of this procedure I need to work with ALL results passed so far, so all must have finished before adding new ones in another iteration of the for-loop.

Comment: @madison54 pls be specific: either you want to wait the queue is empty, or wait all results passed. The difference is that when the queue becomes empty, not all results passed - some are still processed by the pool's threads.

Comment: All threads should have finished execution.